# Pie Chart with static areas or parts

Tags: c#, winforms, wpf-controls, windows-forms-designer

Please need help with a Pie chart in C# Windows Form. What I need basically is a circle divided in three areas, and fill each one independent and without affecting the other parts. I could use WPF but i know not much about it...

Please Help

Comment: Image of an example here
https://www.dropbox.com/s/bbqvewhl09kzypi/Circle%20Static%20Pie.png?dl=0